# Flutter Hook class in Stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, hook, init, statefulwidget

I am trying to have a `Hook` inside a `Stateful Widget` and this is what I tried:

```
class MonthScreen extends Hook<void> {
  final Month month;

  MonthScreen(this.month, {Key key}) : super(key: key); // -> 'named parameter 'key' is not defined'

  @override
  _MonthScreenState createState() => _MonthScreenState(month);
}

class _MonthScreenState extends HookState<void, MonthScreen> {
  final Month month;

  _MonthScreenState(this.month);

  @override
  void initHook() {
    super.initHook();
    //initialize things here
  }
//...
```

What am I doing wrong here? Flutter suggesting changing `key` to `keys` but what do I provide it with then?

Comment: What you need is a `StatefulHookWidget`. Does this answer your question? [flutter class double extends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66459297/flutter-class-double-extends)

Comment: yes it does, thanks!